# Add custom active links to customer account navigation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I am trying to add a custom link in customer account navigation. My custom link is showing in account navigation and working too, but it's not showing as active/current on click.

[image]

Below is the code I have:

> /app/code/Namespace/Support/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-suppport-ticket-link" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">support/customer/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Support Ticket</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> /app/code/Namespace/Support/Controller/Customer/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Support\Controller\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Namespace\Support\Controller\Index
{
    /**
     * Show customer tickets
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> /app/code/Namespace/Support/view/frontend/layout/support_customer_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <head>
        <title>Support Ticket</title>
        <css src="Namespace_Support::css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Support\Block\TicketList" name="ticketViewList" template="Namespace_Support::list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Change the path  from  `<argument name="path" xsi:type="string">support/customer/index</argument>` 
to `<argument name="path" xsi:type="string">support/customer</argument>`

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Comment: @YagneshPonkiya. Thank for your quick reply. Yes, it's working. Put your comment as an answer so  that I can accept.

Comment: @YagneshPonkiya. Also, can you please tell me what was the issue? Why did we need to change that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Shyam, Have you completed this module? I am creating the same functionality in my M2 project. So, could you please guide me how I can create this functionality? Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get the things done, please change the path in your layout file like below.

```
<argument name="path" xsi:type="string">support/customer</argument>
```

Please note, i have removed action part from the path string.

For more information, why you need to do this please study below file.

> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current.php

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: If I have another action name instead of Index , then doesnot not called....

Comment: if you have other action other than "index". you should use full path like "support/customer/abc".

Also make sure your frontname and route id are same.

Comment: @YagneshPonkiya, I am facing same issue at the moment and I have put question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173168/magento-2-create-custom-block-and-phtml-in-magento-customer-module) I have tried with the above code but I am getting 404 page issue.

Comment: @Yagnesh if I am on customer/account/ page then the menu has the class "current". However if I am on customer/account/edit page the "current" class is not present. Can you help? I want to have "current" class on the menu for internal pages as well.

Comment: @YagneshPonkiya What about cms page?

Comment: @YagneshPonkiya You can check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191842/magento-2-show-active-link-of-cms-page-in-customer-account-navigation

Comment: I am not able to do sort order navigation in magento 2.1.0
 Here code - <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</argument>

Answer (score 4):

You can write in your custom layout

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-suppport-ticket-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="current" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```