# Magento 2 add current class in Customer Account dasboard Custom Link

Tags: magento2

I added custom Link In Customer Dashboard. It's Working Fine I want to add **`current`** class if i am in that page

**`Module_index_index.xml`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
          <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Index\Index" name="name" template="template.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

**`customer_account.xml`**

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom-index-index">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">custom/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"> My Link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

Comment: Found correct answer at

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112178/add-custom-active-links-to-customer-account-navigation-in-magento-2

Comment: @kapilyadav we can set the current link on the controller as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways:

1) XML layout: this way is simple. Just change the correct path

```
<argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/custom</argument>
```

Already here: [Add custom active links to customer account navigation in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112178/add-custom-active-links-to-customer-account-navigation-in-magento-2)

2) We can set the current link on the controller:

```
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links $navigationBlock */
    $navigationBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
    if ($navigationBlock) {
        $navigationBlock->setActive('customer/custom');
    }
```

In this way, we just put `<update handle="customer_account"/>`.

module_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <update handle="customer_account"/>
</page>
```

We can take a look here: `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/AbstractController/View.php`

Comment: Hi, We need to remove index from the argument path and it works. Need to correct that in above answer.

Comment: @kapilyadav the first solution?  Feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please add below code in `module_index_index.xml` under body tag

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-custom-index-index">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="is_highlighted" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
        </arguments>
      </referenceBlock>
```

`customer-account-navigation-custom-index-index` is a block name of in  `customer_account.xml`

Final version of your `module_index_index.xml` file :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-custom-index-index">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="is_highlighted" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
        </arguments>
      </referenceBlock> 
      <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
          <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Index\Index" name="name" template="template.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

this will add current class and highlighted automatically when you on that page.